# How to Multi-level Routing with params in Angularjs 2

Tags: angularjs, routes

I can not implement multi-level routing with params in Angular js 2 using router.navigate.

These are my code, just a child route.ts and a component use the navigate, note that I already can use the path '' and 'manageDealers' which mean this route.ts was valid

route.ts

```
export const dealerRoutes : Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dealers',
    children: [
      {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'manageDealers'
      },{
        path: 'manageDealers',
        component: DealerManage,
      },{
        path: ':dealerId/users/:userId',
        name: 'DealerUserDetailManage',
        component: DealerUserDetailManage,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

component.ts

```
viewDetail(dealerId:number,userId:number){
    this.router.navigate([''DealerUserDetailManage',{dealerId: dealerId, userId: userId}]);
  }
```

Did not work

Answer (score 1):

Edit the *route.ts* the default route `redirectTo` needs `/` too. try the code like this:

```
    export const dealerRoutes : Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dealers',
    children: [
      {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: '/manageDealers',
      pathMatch:'full'
      },{
        path: 'manageDealers',
        component: DealerManage,
      },{
        path: ':dealerId/users/:userId',
        name: 'DealerUserDetailManage',
        component: DealerUserDetailManage,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```